# How can I remove occurrences with random hash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, regex

I have a controlled `<input />` in my React application where the user would type.

I want to keep track on it and replace the occurrences of `$.text` and `$.lang` to random hashes/number.

**from**

```js
let string = 'I may have multiple $.text and $.lang like $.textand$.lang';
```

I want all occurrences of $.text and $.lang to have a random number(or anything unique):

**to**

```js
updatedString = 'I may have multiple 123 and 245 like 744and111';
```

> **What I have done so far**

```js
let temp = value.split('').reverse().join(''); // reverse it to find the latest occurrence 
      let reText = /txet.\$/i; 
      let reLang = /gnal.\$/i;
      let updated;
      if (value.includes('$.text')) {
        updated = temp.replace(reText, `${hash}#`); // replace the latest occurrence
      } else {
        updated = temp.replace(reLang, `${hash}#`); // replace the latest occurrence
      }
      updatedValue = updated.split('').reverse().join(''); // re reverse it
```

The issue is it replaces the but onChange RESETS the input state and it only changes the last occurrence of it.

Comment: so you want to replace `$.text` and `$.lang` by random number as soon as user type it? or on but event? like clicking on submit or so?

Comment: Yes, while the user is typing. I can change the code to work around the submit button if that makes it easier

Comment: So if a user types out a sentence and then clicks in the middle of it to type `$.text` then it should be ignored?

Comment: I want the final input state to not have any of $.text or $.lang

Comment: What is a hash exactly? Can a hash produce `$.text` or `$.lang` literally?

Comment: Hash is a custom function I made that returns something like `#sk45le`

Comment: So it's impossible for your function to convert `I may have multiple $.text and` into `I may have multiple #sk4$.lang5le and`?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, thats the crust of the question :/

Comment: You don't understand my question. Upon finding `$.text` is it possible that your custom hash function produces `#sk4$.lang5le` as the output?

Comment: That function doesn't care about any of the value, I am using it to update some state and simply return a random value.

Comment: Yes, I get that. Can that random value be `#sk4$.lang5le` and do you need to deal with that?

Comment: It can be this, it can be anything, as long as it is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So im doing it on click.  So lets say user type something and then clicking on `Replace Template` button will replace the `$.text` and `$.lang` by some random number.  You can insert your specific hash or number if needed.

```
const replaceTemplateByRandom = (val, temp) => {
  while(val.indexOf(temp) != -1){
      const numb = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
      val = val.replace(temp, numb);
  }
  return val;
}
```

inside this arrow function I'm running the while loop till we find the template to replace, and replace occurrence by random number.

```js
const replaceTemplateByRandom = (val, temp) => {
  while(val.indexOf(temp) != -1){
      const numb = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
      val = val.replace(temp, numb);
  }
  return val;
}
function App(props){
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('default text is $.text, and language is $.lang.');
  const updateVal = (e) => {
    const newVal = e.target.value;
    setVal(newVal);
  }
  
  const replaceTemplate = ()=>{
    let currentVal = val;
    currentVal = replaceTemplateByRandom(currentVal, '$.text');
    currentVal = replaceTemplateByRandom(currentVal, '$.lang');
    setVal(currentVal);
  }
  
  return <div>    
    <input type="text" value={val} onChange={updateVal} style={{"width":"100%"}}/>
    
    <button onClick={replaceTemplate}>Replace Template</button>
  </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You're a legend !!

Comment: And we have a quick chat? I have one small query on top of this?

Comment: glad it worked for you, let me know if I can help you.

Comment: Starting a chat with you

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `.replace()`'s acceptance of a function for custom and dynamic substitution:

```js
function myHashFunction(match)
{
    // Uncomment this line to see the various matches coming through
    //console.log(match);
    
    // I'm just returning a random number, you need to change this to your hash algorithm
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(999999999999));
}

let str = `I may have multiple $.text and $.lang like $.textand$.lang`;

console.log(str.replace(/\$\.(?:text|lang)/g, myHashFunction));
```

Comment: Im afraid if `replaceAll` will fail in old browser? when we using regex with global `/g` `replace` will work.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Thanks, I forgot Internet Explorer doesn't support `replaceAll()`

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var theString = "How are $.you doing $.you today?";
    var splitString = theString.split("$.you");
    var joinedString = "";
    for(index = 0; index < splitString.length-1; index++){
        joinedString += splitString[index] + Math.random();
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = joinedString;
}
```

Something simple like this could probably do the job.
So spliting the string into an array of strings and then joining it back with a specific string.
Not React specifically, but the idea is there.

Comment: 1) `str` is undefined so your code is broken. 2) `Math.random()` should be executed once per `$.you` instead of having the value re-used for all `$.you`s

Comment: Sorry, how rude of me to only give a general idea for it. Edited my answer.

Comment: `today?` is missing from `joinedString`